# No prompt or toggle for Android permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat

In my app on Android 7, targetSdkVersion 24, I am trying to request an Android permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. However, when I run the app, it never prompts me for this permission, and when on my device I go to Settings > Apps > MyApp > Permissions, I do not see a toggle for anything related to `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Have I missed a step somewhere?

AndroidManifest.xml (complete file [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gjc1nbZy))

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MyActivity.java

```
int permission = activity.checkSelfPermission(perm);
if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    activity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`? Also, you may want to post the entire manifest, to show where `<uses-permission>` resides.

Comment: @CommonsWare : thanks. I've added a link to the entire manifest, and the `targetSdkVersion` is 24.

Comment: Android 6.0+ runtime permissions are in Settings > Apps > (your app) > Permissions", which does not quite line up with your explanation. Beyond that, try a full uninstall of the app, then reinstall.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks for the correction. I wrote up this SO post while I was away from my workstation, so I constructed that detail from memory (erroneously).

Comment: What is the Android version of your device ?

Comment: @ChristopheCVB : Android version 7.0

Comment: Maybe you installed the app targeting a lower version of Android and thus the permissions has been accepted by default and now it doesn't prompt you... Try uninstall and reinstall :)

Comment: @ChristopheCVB : Thanks, but I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling a few times. What's more, I've also added a line of debugging code to tell me if I lack the expected permission, and the app indicates that I do lack the permission.

Comment: What is `perm` in your code ? Does `perm = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ?

Comment: Last question, does your device has external storage ?

Comment: @JellicleCat I am facing this issue as well recently. 
I was requesting Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and it was working fine for a long time.  But suddenly, now it's always denied, and doesn't prompt when request.
Both Android 6 and 7.

Not able to find a fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time to investigate, I have developed a theory on this issue.

My app has some dependencies that has this in their AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

What this does is auto deny WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission if the SDK is higher than 18.  That's consistent with the issues I am getting;  Permission getting denied and not even prompt the user.

Then I test adding this to my App AndroidManifest.xml in attempt to override the lib dependency permission settings:

```
android:maxSdkVersion="25"
```

It then fails to build due to Merge conflict on masSdkVersion.  This further confirms my suspicions on the issue; the android:maxSdkVersion propagated to the App module.

After digging through the docs, I can't find the solution, but I have a work around.  READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is in the same group as the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and the doc says asking a permission for the same group would apply to the rest of permission for the whole group.

So I tested asking READ permission throughout my App and AndroidManifest.xml, it works, but I think it's stupid.

I will update when I find a proper way to resolved.